# Finding probabilities through normal approximation

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> **Problem:** On each day a gambler wins \$1 with probability 0.91 and loses \$10 with probability 0.09, independently of the other days. With what probability will he have a net loss of \$100 after $n=10000$ days. Use the normal approximation and generous rounding.

**My attempt:** Define $X_i$ as his winnings on the $i$-th day, i.e. $P(X_i=1)=0.91,P(X_i=-10)=0.09$. The $X_i$'s are iid. We have $\mathrm{E}[X_i]=0.01,\mathrm{Var}[X_i]=9.91\approx 9$.

Now we are looking for

$P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\le -100)=P(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-n\cdot\mathrm{E}[X_i]}{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[X_i]}}\le\dfrac{-100-n\cdot\mathrm{E}[X_i]}{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[X_i]}})=P(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-100}{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{9}}\le -\dfrac{2}{3})\approx P(Z_n\le -\dfrac{2}{3})$

by the CLT, where $Z_n$ is standard normal distributed. Looking this up in a table I get a probability of approximately $\dfrac{1}{4}$. That seems a bit high to me. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Numerical answer is a 0.2581 chance of having a loss of $100 or more at the end of the 27-odd years. So your answer looks good.